# Python/Regex - match all sentences matching another regex expression

Tags: python, regex

I use the following regex to match any square brackets containing digits inside them and then ten words preceding and following those brackets 
`(?P<capture>(?:\w+\W+){,10}\[\d+\]\W+(?:\w+\W+){,10})`

This would then return 
`appellant had pleaded guilty: see R v McReady and Hurd [1978] 1 WLR 1376. In those circumstances, the legal advice would`

Now I decided that looking for whole sentences makes more sense, so I want it to find all sentences, however long, including `\[\d+\]\W+` in them.

Any help as how I would do that? I tried different methods but must have made mistakes along the way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding of what you are looking for is, to find all the sentences that contain [number] in it. Try the below pattern with `global` and `multiline` match options on your text:

```
\s+[^.!?]*\[\d+\].*?[.!?]
```

For the example text below you should get two matches which are in bold color:

*Appellant **had pleaded guilty: see R v McReady and Hurd [1978] 1 WLR 1376.** In those circumstances, the legal advice would. **Is there another case [123]?***

Comment: That has worked just fine! Thank you a lot. What. if I were to expand it for any sentence containing either (number) or [number] ? Thanks!

Comment: Write another pattern to match (number) as well. Then you can use `|`(or) operator to merge both results. So, your pattern would become `\s+[^.!?]*\[\d+\].*?[.!?]|\s+[^.!?]*\(\d+\).*?[.!?]`

Comment: Thank you. I forgot to do so :)